# Centering an element with fixed position using non relative values

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to have the #logo element on the right center, using non relative values, which means that if I zoom out it won't zoom out towards the left but towards the center. I need to keep the position on fixed cos I need it to scroll with the #main div.

```
#main {
        margin:0 auto;
        height:1200px;
        width:1200px;
        background-image:url(Background.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    #logo {
        top:20px;
        left:700px;
        margin-left:-177.6px;
        width:355.2px;
        height:148.8px;
        position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML snippet in fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Gaaren/acLd4vs7/ Here it is!

Comment: Don't mind "MyIndex.html" name to the html file, just gave it momentarily..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean with the right center.

1. The left side of the logo is in the center of the page
2. The logo is in the center of the page

[Fiddle for 1 (left side logo centered)](http://jsfiddle.net/pcjndnua/1/) 
change your #logo to

```
#logo {
    width:355.2px;
    height:148.8px;

    top:20px;
    left:50%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

[Fiddle for 2 (logo centered on page)](http://jsfiddle.net/k64g4g4r/1/) 
change your #css and html to:
html

```
<div id="logo-holder">
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#logo-holder{
    position:fixed;    
    left: 50%;
    top: 20px;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    width:355.2px;
    height:148.8px;
    left: -177.6px;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
new fiddle with centered logo in scrolling page
http://jsfiddle.net/k64g4g4r/2/

Comment: I meant logo in the center. When you will resize the window and make it smaller, the logo, with your solution, will move following the window resize, which I said I don't want, therefore I can't use relative values like %. I want it to scroll down and up with the Main div, like they were one single element, but I don't want it to move following the window resize when I resize, so I want it to behave like a static positioned element but just I want it to scroll with the main div.

Comment: If i'm correct. You want a logo at the top of your page (not fixed, but scrollable with the page).. The logo must be centered when the page is loaded? then when resizing the window/browser the logo must stay at the position it was? If this is true: this can't be done with css only. You need to calculate the position of the logo with javascript!

Comment: Updated my answer. Update your question with some images/drawings if this is still not what you want as it's very unclear what you want!

Comment: Yeah Marcel you are right indeed! That is exactly what I mean. So isn't it possible using CSS only?

Comment: Than a few more questions. Is your page width fixed (like 1200px) or the maximum width (width 100%)? If it's fixed: does the logo needs to be centered in the page width? Because it's still not clear to me what you exactly want. I think you just want a normal (centered) logo in your header (wich scrolls with the page). Nothing hard about that (see My update)

Comment: I want a logo centered in the header and scrolling with the page, but staying there when I resize the window. If I put a fixed position it will yes scroll with the page, but it will move towards the side I resize the window, and I don't want that. I don't know what's unclear about it...

Comment: But this logo doesn't scroll with the page. what I mean by logo scrolling with the page is that the logo will follow the page scrolling up and down, so it will vertically be always displayed. In the same time I want the logo not to be subject of any movement due to window resize.. So I want it either: Centered in the middle of the Header; never disappearing scrolling up and down; and not to move on window resize.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k64g4g4r/5/ I'm having trouble getting this working with fiddle as i use this myself in a project. But i gives you a headstart!

Comment: It's ok. I am studying Java Script. I will figure it out using a more powerful language than CSS, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really meant, but if you use left: 75% instead of left: 700px; that might solve it, by using percentages instead of pixels if i understand you correctly

Comment: No it's not correct. The position can't be expressed in relative values such as 0, because as I said I don't want the element to move and follow the window resize. The element must be horizontally centered in the top of the page and still be able to scroll with the main div, as via fixed position. With the values I gave it, those I shared when I asked the question, I get the element to move towards the left when I "zoom out" (not resize window), which means that it won't be displayed in the middle changing resolution. That's basically what I meant.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this myself using CSS only.
What I did is putting the logo in another div, which I called logo container, which I gave a non relative width, which means pixels, rather than percentage.
I put the logo inside so it would appear as fixed as well, and would be centered in the container div (which is the header) by a margin of 0 auto. 
Provided the container div is the amount of pixels I gave wide, it won't be changed by any screen resize, which means that even if the site is opened in a mobile device it will still be PC size, therefore you'd have to scroll left to see the logo, but in the same time the logo will always be there if I scroll up and down.
To sum up, what I achieved is: a logo, that scrolls up and down because the div that I centered it in has a fixed position, and that doesn't "gradually float" when the window is resized, as normally would happen with fixed position element, because the div I put it in has a width in pixels, which means that it's always going to be those pixels, no matter how much you resize. If I had used percentage, like I did before, the width would depend on the size of the window, so it would cause it to "gradually float" on the resize, which I don't want as I explained. To make sure that everything was centered as header I used magin 0 auto.
Thank you anyway for your endeavors. Here's the code I wrote to make it if you simply want to have a look on it.

```
<div id="logocontainer">
<div id="logo">
<a href="MyIndex.html"><img src="Logo.png" width="355.2px" height="148.8px" onMouseOver="this.src='Logo2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='Logo.png'" /></a>
 </div><!--ends logo-->
 </div><!--ends logo container-->

#logocontainer {
        margin:0 auto;
        position:fixed;
        width:1200px;
        height:148.8px;
    }

    #logo {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:355.2px;
        height:148.8px;
    }
```